# Missing the MySQL extension on Nginx and MariaDB

Tags: mysql, wordpress, mariadb

My current configuration is as follows:

1. Macbook Pro 2013 (Mojave)
2. php@7.3
3. mariadb
4. nginx

When accessing WordPress website on my localhost getting this error.

**Your PHP installation appears to be missing the MySQL extension which is required by WordPress.**

While with valet my laravel projects working fine with mariadb > mysql.

What else needs to be configured?

Comment: You need install php-mysql extension. On linux it's apt-get install php-mysql...On mac something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP 7 has thrown out the "mysql_*" interface.

Do not use `php-mysql`, use `php-mysqli` or `php-pdo`.  But, of course, you will need a new enough WP to make use of such.